# Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 arguments, 1 given

Tags: php, html

Estoy copiando un código de login que encontre pero al parecer no esta actualizado a la version de PHP 7, en este proceso me marca este error

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 arguments, 1 given in E:\xampp\htdocs\login\index.php:9 Stack trace: #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\login\index.php(9): mysqli_select_db('tcs_login') #1 {main} thrown in E:\xampp\htdocs\login\index.php on line 9

Como debo formular la linea de codigo para que sea reconocible, adjunto codigo:

```php
<?php 
    $host="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $password="";
    $db="tcs_login";

    mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password);
    mysqli_select_db($db);

    if(isset($_POST['username'])){
    
    $uname=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    
    $sql="select * from tcs_login where email='".$uname."'AND password='".$password."' limit 1";
    
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1){
        echo " You Have Successfully Logged in";
        exit();
    }
    else{
        echo " You Have Entered Incorrect Password";
        exit();
    }
        
    }
?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
     <title> Login Form in HTML5 and CSS3</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" a href="./style.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" a href="css\font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
     <div class="container">
     <img src="image/login.png"/>
        <form>
            <div class="form-input">
                <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Enter the User Name"/>  
            </div>
            <div class="form-input">
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"/>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" type="submit" value="LOGIN" class="btn-login"/>
        </form>
      </div>
      </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Te falta el link, tal como ilustran leyendo su [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.select-db.php) : `mysqli_select_db(mysqli $link, string $dbname): bool`

Answer (score 0):

Si lees la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.select-db.php) verás que `mysqli_select_db` necesita dos parámetros:

1. La conexión
2. El nombre de la base de datos.

Ahora bien, **no estás guardando una referencia a la conexión cuando conectas**, debes guardar dicha referencia para usarla posteriormente.

Dicha referencia se crea cuando invocas a `mysqli_connect()`. Por otra parte, **no necesitas usar `mysqli_select_db()` para este caso, porque `mysqli` te permite seleccionar la base de datos al conectar, pasándola como **cuarto parámetro**.

En tu código se ven más errores, por ejemplo, tampoco pasas la conexión cuando usas `mysql_query()`, además, estás usando la función antigua, sin la `i`. Usas también la función antigua, sin la `i` con `mysql_num_rows()`, esas funciones fueron sacadas del núcleo de PHP desde la versión 7.

Intenta pues de este modo:

```
<?php 

    $host="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $password="";
    $db="tcs_login";
    
    $mysqli=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);
    
    if ($mysqli) {
        $uname=$_POST['username'] ?? null;
        $password=$_POST['password'] ?? null;
        if($uname && $password) {
            $sql="select COUNT(*) from tcs_login where email='$uname' AND password='$password' limit 1";
            if ($result=mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
                $row=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
                if ($row[0] ==1) {
                    $msg="You Have Successfully Logged in";
                } else {
                    $msg="You Have Entered Incorrect Password";
                }
            } else {
                $msg="SQL query error";
            }
        } else {
            $msg="No data posted";
        }
    } else {
        $msg="No connection to DB";
    }
    echo $msg;
    exit();    
?>
```

Yo he tratado de escribir un código controlado, de modo que siempre sepas lo que ha ocurrido. He optimizado otras cosas, por ejemplo, es mejor hacer un conteo de filas cuando lo que se quiere es verificar la existencia de registros. `num_rows` depende a veces del buffer, y según la configuración puede dar problemas en algunos escenarios.

Habría otras cosas a mejorar, como la **seguridad**. Tu actual código es altamente vulnerable  a ataques de *inyección SQL*. Deberías usar consultas preparadas para prevenir ese riesgo.